# lodash's min returning wrong value from an array of negative values

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have this array of negative values:

```
["-117.911732", "-112.0756724", "-71.0595678", "-78.8783689", "-114.0833", "-78.6390779", "-87.6244212", "-104.9847034", "-83.0007065", "-96.7968994", "-83.0567375", "-113.5000", "-80.1936589", "-118.2427266", "-93.1015026", "-73.5833", "-86.78086153", "-74.1723667", "-73.9865812", "-73.9865812", "-75.7000", "-75.163789", "-79.9900861", "-121.8831349", "-90.1978889", "-82.458444", "-79.4167", "-123.1333", "-77.0366456", "-97.1667"]
```

Lodash's [_.min](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#min) function returns `-104.9847034` instead of `-123.1333` which is obviously wrong? What do I miss?

Here is the running example: http://codepen.io/neptune01/pen/XMOeVM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have array of string so you need to first convert strings to numbers using `_.map`.

```js
var arr = ["-117.911732", "-112.0756724", "-71.0595678", "-78.8783689", "-114.0833", "-78.6390779", "-87.6244212", "-104.9847034", "-83.0007065", "-96.7968994", "-83.0567375", "-113.5000", "-80.1936589", "-118.2427266", "-93.1015026", "-73.5833", "-86.78086153", "-74.1723667", "-73.9865812", "-73.9865812", "-75.7000", "-75.163789", "-79.9900861", "-121.8831349", "-90.1978889", "-82.458444", "-79.4167", "-123.1333", "-77.0366456", "-97.1667"];
console.log(_.min(_.map(arr, Number)))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.15.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Another version would be: `_(arr).map(Number).min()`